# how to check if value already exists in txt file

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am writing UserID's to a text file seperated with `||`
The  var `$UserID` is an integer like 1, 2, 3 etc.

If a user has ID 1; the value is stored in the txt file and looks after some time like this:

`1||1||1||1||1||...`

What i want to achieve:
 if an ID is already stored in the txt file, do not store it again.

this is what i have sofar;

```
$UserIdtxt = $UserID."||";


$ID = explode("||", file_get_contents("user_id.txt"));
  foreach($ID as $IDS) {

// here must come the check if the ID already is stored in the txt file
     if($IDS != $UserID) {
     file_put_contents("user_id.txt", $UserIdtxt, FILE_APPEND);

     }
  }
```

How can i make that check?

Comment: before you get too far into solving this problem, have you considered using a database management system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is test if the new ID is aleady in the exploded array using `in_array()`

```
$UserIdtxt = $UserID."||";

$all_ids = explode("||", file_get_contents("user_id.txt"));

if ( ! in_array($UserID, $all_ids) ) {
    file_put_contents("user_id.txt", $UserIdtxt, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

> But this is an awful way of storing this kind of information

Comment: Flat-file might be *yuck*, but is fast.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Not when there are 10000 ids in the file. Then its just a cumbersome mess

Comment: This works fine. But i do agree; it is more proper to put the data in a DB

Comment: @RiggsFolly :) I agree on that

Answer (score 0):

Prob a good idea to make sure the file was read successfully before you scan it

```
if($source = file_get_contents("user_id.txt"){
    if(!preg_match("/^($UserID|.*\|\|$UserID)/", $source){
        ... //add id to file
    }
}else{/*Todo: handle file-open failure*/}
```